# How to select all attributes in sql Join query

Tags: sql, oracle

The following sql query below produces the specified result.

```
 select product.product_no,product_type,salesteam.rep_name,salesteam.SUPERVISOR_NAME
 from product
 inner join salesteam
 on product.product_rep=salesteam.rep_id
 ORDER BY product.Product_No;
```

However my intensions are to further produce a more detailed result which will include all the attributes in the PRODUCT table. my approach is to list all the attributes in the first line of the query.

```
 select product.product_no,product.product_date,product.product_colour,product.product_style,
 product.product_age product_type,salesteam.rep_name,salesteam.SUPERVISOR_NAME
 from product
 inner join salesteam
 on product.product_rep=salesteam.rep_id
 ORDER BY product.Product_No;
```

Is there another way it can be done instead of listing all the attributes of PRoduct table one by one?

Comment: @ andrefsp, am using sqlplus from oracle 10g

Comment: So the title is completely misleading - not the join is the problem, only the selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` to select all columns from all tables, or you can use `[table/alias].*` to select all columns from the specified table. In your case, you can use `product.*`:

```
select product.*,salesteam.rep_name,salesteam.SUPERVISOR_NAME
from product
inner join salesteam
on product.product_rep=salesteam.rep_id
ORDER BY product.Product_No;
```

It is important to note that **you should only do this if you are 100% sure you need every single column, and always will**. There are performance implications associated with this; if you're selecting 100 columns from a table when you really only need 4 or 5 of them, you're adding a lot of overhead to the query. The DBMS has to work harder, and you're also sending more data across the wire (if your database is not on the same machine as your executing code).

If any columns are later added to the `product` table, those columns will also be returned by this query in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select 
      product.*, 
      salesteam.rep_name,
      salesteam.SUPERVISOR_NAME
 from product inner join salesteam on 
      product.product_rep=salesteam.rep_id
 ORDER BY 
      product.Product_No;
```

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can  write like this

```
select P.*  ---  all Product columns 
,S.* --- all salesteam columns
 from product P
 inner join salesteam S
 on P.product_rep=S.rep_id
 ORDER BY P.Product_No;
```

Comment: i used a similar approach but i keep getting errors                      select area.*,
       customer.*,
 from area inner join customer on
       area.area_number=customer.area;                                                                                                           *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: i have gotten it.. thanx, i removed a comma